# Does the concept of global and local variable differ in python and javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

I know Python a bit, I am trying to learn JS and getting a bit confused about the concepts of Global and Local variables in JS. Like in this code in JS --->

```js
function queue(arr, item){
  arr.push(item)
  arr.shift()

}
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
queue(a, 6)
console.log(a)   // O/P : [2,3,4,5,6]
```

Output --> [2,3,4,5,6]

But this output is not possible in Python.
Another code in JS --->

```js
glo = 14
function myWorld(){
  lo = ++glo
  glo = 5
  return l
}

console.log(myWorld())   // O/P : 15
console.log(glo)        // O/P : 5
```

This is also not possible in python. This is possible in python if `glo` is a list and we update `glo[i] = 5` inside the function. I am getting confused. Please help and I would appreciate if you provide a good resource for learning JS.

I am a 2020 Grad. I am also preparing for interviews and kind of feeling lost in the way, any help will be much appreciated. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Why do you think these things are impossible in Python? You might have to write things a little bit, because of stuff like different method names and different variable declaration rules (and by the way, you've screwed up your variable declarations), but it's possible to write a fairly direct translation.

Comment: I think this is possible if I use `global` keyword in Python inside the function. Right ? But I am not getting the first code, where I am not updating the variable but still it is getting updated. And which variable declaration are you talking about, please tell me. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: "*which variable declaration are you talking about*" all of your JS variables (aside from the function parameters in the firstone) are implicitly global, since you haven't declared them with `var`, `let`, or `const`

Comment: Can you post some Python code that you've tried that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Array is passed to the function by reference. So when you `shift` you aren't shifting on a copy of it but on the array itself modyfing it.

Python behave the same if you for example define:

```
def queue(arr, item):
    arr.append(item)
    arr.pop(0)
```

In general you can search some tutorials relative to the concept of `scope` in js.

See for example [js scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Comment: The method on Python `list`s is `append`, not `push`.

Comment: Thank you you're right!

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Nja